# Correlation of two samples with replicates

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics

I have a expression values (log2) for 200 genes in two conditions treated and untreated and for each condition I have 20 replicates. I want to calculate the correlation between each condition for each gene and rank them from highest to lowest.

This is more of a biostats problem, but still I think it is an important one for biologists/bio-programmers many of us encounter this.

The dataset looks like this:

```
Gene    UT1            UT2            T1             T2  
DDR1     8.111795978    7.7606511867   7.9362235824   7.5974674936
RFC2    10.2418824097   9.7752152714  10.0085488406   9.5723427524
HSPA6    6.5850239731   6.7916563534   6.6883401632   7.3659252344
PAX8     9.2965160827   9.2031177653   9.249816924    8.667772504
GUCA1A   5.4828021059   5.3797749957   5.4312885508   5.1297319374
```

I have shown only two replicates for each sample in the sample data.

I am looking for a solution in R or python.
cor function in R does not give me what i want.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what it is you want and why the `cor` function in R doesn't do it? For instance, is it this? (1) For each gene, you have two length-20 vectors of numbers, one for the untreated condition and one for the treated condition. (2) You want to compute the correlation coefficient between those two vectors. (3) Then you want to sort the genes according to the value of those correlation coefficients.

Comment: If it's something like that, then what part of the problem is giving you trouble? Extracting the particular bits of data you want to correlate? Computing the correlation numbers? Doing the sorting?

Comment: In this case t-test needs to be applied as their are sample replicates. Which implies that two samples can be similar based on some sort of p-value/significance value.

Comment: Yes, you could use a t-test if, e.g., the question you're really interested in is whether the two conditions produce the same mean value for your statistic (rather than, say, whether they have the same variance). It seems to me that the question of what you should do to compare the data for a single gene is a biostats question rather than a programming question, and you'll probably get more expert answers to it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from your question,you need to calculate correlation between UT1 and T1 and UT2 and T2 for all the Genes.
There is a way to do it in R :

```
df <- data.frame(Gene = c("DDR1","RFC2","HSPA6","PAX8","GUCA1A")
, UT1 =  c(8.111796, 10.241882,  6.585024 , 9.296516 , 5.482802),
UT2 =c( 7.760651 ,9.775215 ,6.791656, 9.203118, 5.379775),
T1 =c(7.936224 ,10.008549,  6.688340 , 9.249817 , 5.431289),
T2 =c(7.597467 ,9.572343 ,7.365925 ,8.667773 ,5.129732))
```

make a matrix like this :

```
mat1 <- cbind(file$UT1,file$T1)
```

initialize a correlation matrix :

```
cor1 <- matrix(0,length(file$Gene),length(file$Gene))
```

then calculate correlation all against all genes like this :

```
for(i in 1:length(df$Gene)) cor1[i,] = apply(mat1,1,function(x) cor(x,mat1[df$Gene[i],]))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think t-test should be applied to see how similar expression is in two samples.

Comment: According to your question I thought that you wanted to calculate correlation.

Answer (score 1):

All sources I've read indicate that you need to create an *average* measure for each replicate. I've seen both `mean` and `median` used, although you may want to look into more advanced pre-processing/normalization methods (like `RMA`). Once you've done that you can calculate the correlation between untreated and treated.

There is no way to calculate correlation in the way that you're looking for. Any method that would do so will ultimately boil down to summarizing the information across the two conditions through getting a summary probe measure across the replicates (as above).

Alternatively you could do something like calculate the correlation between each treated and untreated replicate for each probe, and take the average correlation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first column account for the names of the rows and first column for their names, i.e., assuming that your data contains only numeric values, you can simply do the following in R, which will give you a n x n matrix with all pairwise correlations between genes.

cor(data)

You may want to specify what type of correlation you want to use... What is the length of the time-series? There are whole studies developed to address the issue of selecting an appropriate measure, e.g., see:

Pablo A. Jaskowiak, Ricardo J. G. B. Campello, Ivan G. Costa Filho, "Proximity Measures for Clustering Gene Expression Microarray Data: A Validation Methodology and a Comparative Analysis," IEEE/ACM Transactions on Computational Biology and Bioinformatics, vol. 99, no. PrePrints, p. 1, , 2013